# Why is there no markov-decision-processes tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Markov decision processes are a fundamental model for sequential decision making frequently studied by computer scientists.

To my surprise, there is no related tag in either the CS or CS Theory sites. The closest related tag is markov-chains, which is quite broad. I think there is a lot to be gained by introducing a tag specific to MDPs.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Answer (score 0):

If there is no tag, the most likely explanation is that nobody ever needed it. Otherwise, they'd have created it; typically, we have problems of *too many* tags as opposed to the other way around.

Do have a list of existing questions that, in your opinion, *should* have been tagged with [markov-decision-processes](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/markov-decision-processes)?

One thing to keep in mind that everybody tends to overestimate the global relevance of their own topics-of-heart. That said, there is no rule that says tags can only exist for topics clearing some arbitrary relevance (read: popularity) threshold. If you have a question that warrants the tag, just use and thereby create it!